# Sed regex to match content in between " "

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace anything between " " in the following file with xx.

ORIGINAL FILE

```
event syslog pattern "random text" maxrun 50 ratelimit 50
action 0.1 cli command "random text"
action 0.2 cli command "random text"
action 0.4 cli command "random text"
action 0.4 cli command "random text"
action 0.3 cli command "random text"
action 0.4 cli command "random text"
action 0.5 cli command "random text"
action 0.6 cli command "random text"
action 0.7 cli command "random text"
action 0.8 cli command "random text"
action 0.9 cli command "random text"
action 1.1 cli command "random text"
action 1.2 cli command "random text"
action 1.3 cli command "random text"
action 1.4 cli command "random text"
action 1.5 cli command "random text"
action 1.6 cli command "random text"
action 1.7 cli command "random text"
action 1.8 cli command "random text"
action 1.9 cli command "random text"
action 2.1 cli command "random text"
action 2.2 cli command "random text"
action 2.3 cli command "random text"
```

I've used sed for this, but the first case does not work. Can I get some explanation around the syntax?

Case 1: Why aren't the original " " retained when replacing with xx?

First attempt - non-working

```
$ sed -e 's/\".*\"/xx/g' eem.txt
event manager applet monitorHealth authorization bypass
event manager applet monitorHealth
event syslog pattern xx maxrun 50 ratelimit 50
action 0.1 cli command xx
action 0.2 cli command xx
action 0.4 cli command xx
action 0.4 cli command xx
action 0.4 cli command "undebug all”
action 0.3 cli command xx
action 0.4 cli command xx
action 0.5 cli command xx
action 0.6 cli command xx
action 0.7 cli command xx
action 0.8 cli command xx
action 0.9 cli command xx
action 1.1 cli command xx
action 1.2 cli command xx
action 1.3 cli command xx
action 1.4 cli command xx
action 1.5 cli command xx
action 1.6 cli command xx
action 1.7 cli command xx
action 1.8 cli command xx
action 1.9 cli command xx
action 2.1 cli command xx
action 2.2 cli command xx
action 2.3 cli command xx
```

Second attempt - working

Case 2: Can I get some explanation around "[^"]*"? From what I have seen [^"]* means do not match character ", but I'm unable to put the logic together.

```
$  sed -n 's/"[^"]*"/"xx"/gp' eem.txt
event syslog pattern "xx" maxrun 50 ratelimit 50
action 0.1 cli command "xx"
action 0.2 cli command "xx"
action 0.4 cli command "xx"
action 0.4 cli command "xx"
action 0.3 cli command "xx"
action 0.4 cli command "xx"
action 0.5 cli command "xx"
action 0.6 cli command "xx"
action 0.7 cli command "xx"
action 0.8 cli command "xx"
action 0.9 cli command "xx"
action 1.1 cli command "xx"
action 1.2 cli command "xx"
action 1.3 cli command "xx"
action 1.4 cli command "xx"
action 1.5 cli command "xx"
action 1.6 cli command "xx"
action 1.7 cli command "xx"
action 1.8 cli command "xx"
action 1.9 cli command "xx"
action 2.1 cli command "xx"
action 2.2 cli command "xx"
action 2.3 cli command "xx"
```

Thanks.

Comment: "undebug all” contains a closing double quote (`E2 80 9D` in UTF-8) which does not match with ASCII double quote character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first example:

```
$ sed -e 's/\".*\"/xx/g' eem.txt
```

The double quotes do not appear in the replacement, because you never put them there.  If you want to replace with `"xx"`, then do that:

```
$ sed -e 's/\".*\"/"xx"/g' eem.txt
```

For your second example:

```
$  sed -n 's/"[^"]*"/"xx"/gp' eem.txt
```

This will replace with `"xx"`, but only because you used double quotes in the replacement.  As for `"[^"]*"`, this just says to match a double quote, followed by any number of *non* double quote characters, followed by another double quote.

In some regex flavors, e.g. Perl, we could also write `".*?"` to do the same thing.  This is called the lazy dot, and means that it will consume anything up until the *first* double quotation found.

Comment: Does it mean that [^"]*" is functionally equivalent to \".*\" in this example? As there is only one instance of double quotes in the sample file.

Comment: No, they are not the same, at least not in the case where `.*` could match across lines.  In general `".*"` will match a double quote, until the _last_ double quote.  If you want to match each individual term in double quotes, then you should be using either `"[^"]*"` or `".*?"`, depending on your regex flavor.